# Print and edit pointer by address in c

Tags: c, pointers

I want to print the value into pointer and edit the pointer's value that located at 0xabcd address

For example 0xabcd ->0xeeeee , I want that 0xabcd will point to 0xaaaa.

```
int * buff = 0xabcd;
print("the value is %p",*buff); // here is want to see 0xeeeee 
*buff =0xaaaa;
```

is that right?

Comment: What makes you think that `0xeeeee` would be the value stored at that particular address?

Comment: Making a pointer point to an address without a valid object will cause undefined behavior according to the ISO C standard.

Comment: @Bob__ that constant  address

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "that constant address"?

Comment: If it is your intention to explore the memory in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your own process, then this is possible, but not in ISO C. You will require platform-specific functions. In that case, please specify your platform (operator system and CPU).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

```
int * buff = 0xabcd;
```

It assigns the pointer with the integer value converted to pointer to int. It is very very unlikely the address 0xabcd to point to the int array. Dereferencing it invokes Undefined Behaviour.

The `%p` is to print pointer not the integer referenced by it. Second UB

```
int a,b;
int * buff = &a;
print("the value is %p",(void *)buff); 
*buff =0xaaaa;
print("the value is %d",*buff); 
buff = &b;
print("the value is %p",(void *)buff);
```

But this form us used very often in the low level programming where we know the addresses of the hardware registers or buffers.

Example:

```
volatile int *ADC_Result = (volatile int *)0x45000000;
```

Then you can see what is in this register

```
printf("ADC value: %d\n", *ADC_Result);
```

But you need to use the correct format (in this case `%d` to print the integer)

Comment: So I didn't understand how to watch the value into address `0xabcd`